# Prolog maplist on inner term?

Tags: list, prolog, functor, maplist

How to use maplist on inner term?

Assuming the KB is:

```
gate(not(o), i). 
gate(not(i), o).

gate(and(o, i), o).
gate(and(i, o), o).
gate(and(B, B), B).

bits([i,o,o,i,i]).
```

The following is not working:
`?- bits(BITS), maplist(gate(not(X), Y), BITS, ANS)`

How can I map over the list so that:

`[i,o,o,i,i]` -> `[not(i), not(o), not(o), not(i), not(i)]` ->`[o,i,i,o,o]`

This is to be done on any list length:

```
:- bits([A,B,C,D,E]), gate(not(A), Anew), gate(not(B), Bnew), gate(not(C), Cnew), gate(not(D), Dnew), gate(not(E), Enew), ANS = [Anew, Bnew, Cnew, Dnew, Enew].
```

So that the answer would be: `ANS = [o, i, i, o, o]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a helper predicate:

```
not(A, Z) :-
    gate(not(A), Z).

?- bits(BITS), maplist(not, BITS, ANS).

ANS  = [o, i, i, o, o],
BITS = [i, o, o, i, i]
```

But if you are going to add two lines of helper, skip the `gate()` stuff and write directly:

```
not(o, i).
not(i, o).

?- bits(BITS), maplist(not, BITS, ANS).

ANS  = [o, i, i, o, o],
BITS = [i, o, o, i, i]
```

If you don't want to do that, or cannot change the database at all, the only way I know is using a lambda library such as [yall](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall) in SWI Prolog, [others may be available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65875932/lambdas-in-prolog) to write this:

```
?- bits(BITS), maplist([In, Out]>>gate(not(In), Out), BITS, ANS).

ANS  = [o, i, i, o, o],
BITS = [i, o, o, i, i]
```

(It might be bad form to name it `not`, but this is `not/2` and the builtin is `not/1` so I don't think it will clash).

Comment: I can change it, but if I write it as `not(A, B)` then wouldn't be able to write something like: `gate(and(A, or(not(A), B)),  and(A, B))` meaning `a.(!a+b) = a.b` ... or would I? I'm new to prolog, I'm trying to writing a logic circuit simplifier (like wolfalpha does it, by rewriting the formula first) then evaluating it by mapping over the values ... Lambdas should be part of the prolog standard, I'm surprised it's not, I'm downloading the library, thanks for the links

Comment: @Mustafa I don't know; I cannot make sense of what you are doing so far. I don't think maplist is complex enough to help you process arbitrary nested trees like that `gate(and(A, or(...` structure and you will probably need recursive predicates to handle that.